# Six digit unicode escaped value comparison

Tags: c#, unicode, unicode-escapes

I have a six digit unicode character, for example `U+100000` which I wish to make a comparison with a another `char` in my C# code.

My reading of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669.aspx) is that this character cannot be represented by a `char`, and must instead be represented by a `string`.

> a Unicode character in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF is not permitted in a character literal and is represented using a Unicode surrogate pair in a string literal

I feel that I'm missing something obvious, but how can you get the follow comparison to work correctly:

```
public bool IsCharLessThan(char myChar, string upperBound)
{
    return myChar < upperBound; // will not compile as a char is not comparable to a string
}

Assert.IsTrue(AnExample('\u0066', "\u100000"));
Assert.IsFalse(AnExample("\u100000", "\u100000")); // again won't compile as this is a string and not a char
```

**edit**

k, I think I need two methods, one to accept chars and another to accept 'big chars' i.e. strings.  So:

```
public bool IsCharLessThan(char myChar, string upperBound)
{
    return true; // every char is less than a BigChar
}

public bool IsCharLessThan(string myBigChar, string upperBound)
{
    return string.Compare(myBigChar, upperBound) < 0;
}

Assert.IsTrue(AnExample('\u0066', "\u100000));
Assert.IsFalse(AnExample("\u100022", "\u100000"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To construct a string with the Unicode code point U+10FFFF using a string literal, you need to work out the [surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) involved.

In this case, you need:

```
string bigCharacter = "\uDBFF\uDFFF";
```

Or you can use `char.ConvertFromUtf32`:

```
string bigCharacter = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x10FFFF);
```

It's not clear what you want your method to achieve, but if you need it to work with characters not in the BMP, you'll need to make it accept `int` instead of `char`, or a `string`.

As per the documentation for [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), if you want to iterate over characters in a string as full Unicode values, use [`TextElementEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx) or [`StringInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx).

Note that you *do* need to do this explicitly. If you just use ordinal values, it will check *UTF-16* code units, not the UTF-32 code points. For example:

```
string text = "\uF000";
string upperBound = "\uDBFF\uDFFF";
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(text, upperBound, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

This prints out a value greater than zero, suggesting that `text` is greater than `upperBound` here. Instead, you should use [`char.ConvertToUtf32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b.aspx):

```
string text = "\uF000";
string upperBound = "\uDBFF\uDFFF";
int textUtf32 = char.ConvertToUtf32(text, 0);
int upperBoundUtf32 = char.ConvertToUtf32(upperBound, 0);
Console.WriteLine(textUtf32 < upperBoundUtf32); // True
```

So that's probably what you need to do in your method. You might want to use [`StringInfo.LengthInTextElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.lengthintextelements.aspx) to check that the strings really are single UTF-32 code points first.

Comment: Hi Jon. I want to check that a character is in a custom range.  I simplified the example by just doing a check of one end of the range.  But \u10FFFF is not less than \u10FFFF though!

Comment: @sprocketonline: Yes, but you can't specify `U+10FFFF` as a `char`. That's my point. If you need to take non-BMP characters into account, you've *got* to make your method accept those characters.

Comment: but `\u10FFFF` is a bit of a silly example to use (given that `\u10FFFF` is the only value that it won't compare true with). I've therefore changed the example to something hopefully a bit better.

Comment: @sprocketonline: The answer would still be `true`, because every `char` is less than U+100000 as well. Every `char` is in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF inclusive.

Comment: very good point Jon!  I've edited and cleaned up the examples.

Comment: @sprocketonline: Why would you need to specify an upper bound as a string if you only have a `char` to test? Any time a `char` has any chance of being greater than or equal to the upper bound, that upper bound can be expressed as a `char` as well.

Comment: @sprocketonline: See my edit which walks you through a few more bits.

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa664669.aspx, you have to use `\U` with full 8 hex digits. So for example:

```
string str1 = "\U0001F300";
string str2 = "\uD83C\uDF00";
bool eq = str1 == str2;
```

using the [:cyclone:](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f300/index.htm) emoji.